# How to populate the box in different vertical lines, only use the `nth-child` selector?

Tags: html, css

How to use `nth-child` to realize the Horizontal 3 three, and the vertical is 300px per three. 1 2 3,4 5 6,7 8 9,10 11 12,..., the number of the box will change.
   This is my code:

```
<style>
    .big-box {
        /*position: relative;*/
        width: 900px;
        background-color: aqua;
        margin:  200px auto;
    }

   .big-box .middle-box {
       height: 300px;
       position: relative;
        background-color: gold;
    }

    .small-box {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border-radius: 150px;
        color: white;
        line-height: 300px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 150px;
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }

    .small-box:nth-child(3n+1) {
      left: 0;
       top: 0;
    }
    .small-box:nth-child(3n+2) {
        left: 300px;
        top: 0;
    }
    .small-box:nth-child(3n+0) {
        left: 600px;
        top: 0;
    }

</style>



<div class="big-box">
      <div class="middle-box">
      <div class="small-box">1</div>
      <div class="small-box">2</div>
      <div class="small-box">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="middle-box">
      <div class="small-box">4</div>
      <div class="small-box">5</div>
      <div class="small-box">6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="middle-box">
      <div class="small-box">7</div>
      <div class="small-box">8</div>
      <div class="small-box">9</div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

How can I  do to realize this, only use the `nth-child`, not use the `middle-box` div? If I delete the `middle-box`div, how to populate the `3(n+x)` box in different vertical lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you would even need any of that? Just stick all the `small-box` `div`s into `big-box`, set `display: inline-block`, and remove all absolute positioning.

Don't forget to either remove spaces between the inner `div`s or set `font-size: 0` to make sure there's no space between the `small-box`es.

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jacquesc/9djnfb9m/